# Import com.almworks.sqlite4java without maven

Tags: java

I'm currently learning Java (moving from C#). In order to learn how everything works I am trying to do as much as possible manually.

I'm developing my applications using vim, and the java compiler. I'm having trouble importing sqlite 4 java. I added the jar to the classpath by doing: `javac -cp ".:sqlite4java.jar" *.java;`. When I attempt to import sqlite4java (`import com.almworks.sqlite4java;`) I get the error:

```
package com.almworks does not exist   
import com.almworks.sqlite4java;
```

I can't for the life of me work out why this error is ocurring. I have successfully imported and used Gson using the same method with no issues.

I can only assume it is because of the platform specific dependencies sqlite4java has. I've tried running the java compiler with verbose output but it isn't providing any useful information. The dependencies are in the same directory as the jar file.

Preferably I would like to stay away from maven until I'm confident doing it manually.

Edit: I should also note that I have tried using wildcards for the classpath.

Comment: `javac -cp ".:sqlite4java"`: I can't see any jar file listed here. A jar file name ends with `.jar`. Also, the double quotes are not needed.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in the question. Please see the update :).

Comment: On which OS are you working? Do you have a file named sqlite4java.jar in the current directory? What's the output of `ls`? And of `jar tvf sqlite4java.jar`

Comment: And the jar in the folder where you call `javac`?

Comment: I am using Debian. Yes the sql4litejava.jar file is in the current directory. `ls` shows that the jar is infact in the current directory. Here is the output requested: http://pastebin.com/XqZxav6L

Comment: Use of an IDE is heavily recommended, if only for the automatic import statement generation. You can avoid build-automation, but Java has a tendency to split functionality in a dozen places, and imports are not transitive (unlike `#include`s), so not using an IDE is quite a burden on knowing what to import for everything you use.

Comment: I'd rather power through it for now :). That way I can really understand what makes this tick. I don't like it when the IDE does all the work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`com.almworks.sqlite4java` is a package. You may not import a package. You can import a class, or all classes in a package:

```
import com.almworks.sqlite4java.*;
```

or better, import only the classes that you're actually using:

```
import com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConnection;
import com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConstants;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yourimport statement is wrong.

If you would like to import all classes from a packeg you have to use:

```
import com.almworks.sqlite4java.*;
```